# Object response ajax returned as undefined

Tags: javascript, ajax

This problem is literally sending me crazy. Practically exhaust values performando an ajax request, so far so good in their methods the php json is returned correctly with all fields and also that indicted: unavailables. This field is not seen by the class and I get the answer ajax returns undefined, perhaps with the code I can explain better:

**Ajax request**

```
$.post(postUrl, postData, function(response) 
    {
        console.log(response);
        console.log(response.unavailables);
        ...
```

response result in console.log

[image]

and response.unavailables in console.log

[image]

How you can see in the response I get correctly the `unavailables array`, but the code doesn't see this, I've checked the php class for hours, check the results and other stuff all correct! Infact the value unavailables is returned but for a strange reasons I get an undefined. Why happean this?

**Matteo solution**

```
$.each(response, function(_, obj) 
                        {
                            $.each(obj, function(key, val) 
                            {
                                if (key === 'unavailables') 
                                {
                                    console.log("val => " , val);
                                }
                            });
                        });
```

[image]

More details:

[image]

Comment: How about response[0].unavailables ?

Comment: In other words... pay attention to the indention level...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is `response[0].unavailables`.

If you look at your data structure in the console log, in fact, you see that `unavailables` is at the same level as `appointments`, which is inside key `0`, hence `unavailables` is too.

EDIT: the only way I can think of to cycle all `unavailables` is as follows:

```
$.each(response, function(_, obj) {
    $.each(obj, function(key, val) {
        if (key === 'unavailables') {
            // here you go
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: It's possible access to all level without a reference for index? Like so:
$.each(response.unavailables, function(index, unavailable)  ??

Comment: Given your current data structure, I'd say "no".

Comment: Could you suggest me a modality similar to $.each? 'Cause if response[0].unavailables is empty the code broke to undefined..

Comment: @Dillinger see my edit!

Comment: Okay interesting, but in the condition if I do: console.log(key['notes']); or console.log(key.notes); the console return undefined, why?

Comment: Because `key` is, obviously, the key in the object, not the object itself, which is `val`, so if you want the notes, it is `val.notes`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/93059/discussion-between-dillinger-and-matteo-tassinari).

Comment: Sorry I've write key but instead I've tried with val.notes and val['notes'] still return undefined also See my image updated in the topic

Answer (score 2):

So you can access the item using...

```
response[i].unavailables
```

Where i is the index.

For example...

```
for (var i = 0; i < response.length; i++) {
    console.log(response[i].unavailables.id);
}
```

Comment: It's possible access to all level without a reference for index? Like so: $.each(response.unavailables, function(index, unavailable) ??